# Using Xcode, Swift, and GRDB, why do I have to unwrap DatabaseQueue? before I can use its methods?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using the GRDB library to integrate SQLite with my iOS application project. I declared a DatabaseQueue object in AppDelegate.swift like so:

```
var DB : DatabaseQueue!
```

In the same file, I had provided a function for connecting the above object to a SQLite database which is called when the app starts running. I had been able to use this in one of my controllers without problems (as in, the app doesn't have problems running using the database I connected to it), like so:

```
var building : Building?
do {
    try DB.write { db in
        let building = Building.fetchOne(db, "SELECT * FROM Building WHERE number = ?", arguments: [bldgNumber])
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

However, in another controller, the same construct is met with an error,

```
Value of optional type 'DatabaseQueue?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'write' of wrapped base type 'DatabaseQueue'
```

with the only difference (aside from the code, of course) being that there are return statements inside the do-catch block, as the latter is inside a function (tableView for numberOfRowsInSection) that is supposed to return an integer. The erroneous section of code is shown below.

```
var locsCountInFloor : Int
do {
    try DB.write { db in
        if currentBuilding!.hasLGF == true {
            locsCountInFloor = IndoorLocation.filter(bldg == currentBuilding! && level == floor).fetchCount(db)
        } else {
            locsCountInFloor = IndoorLocation.filter(bldg == currentBuilding! && level == floor + 1).fetchCount(db)
        }
        return locsCountInFloor
    }
} catch {
    return 0
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show how DB is declared in the file causing issues.

Comment: I don't think that second code block will work for you anyway; you are trying to `return` a value from an asynchronous closure.

Comment: The relevant difference is the type of the `DB` variable. In the erroneous controller, it has the `DatabaseQueue?` type. This is clearly written in the error message. The error message also tells you to "unwrap" the optional value. If you are not familiar with those terms, I recommend you read the documentation about Optionals in the Swift book: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330

Comment: @GwendalRoué The relevant difference is **not** the type of `DB`. It can be declared an IUO and still produce this error. Please see my answer for details.

Comment: I should say that the relevant difference is **not necessarily** the type of `DB`. If `DB` is declared `DatabaseQueue?`, it will certainly produce this error, and we haven’t seen the relevant declaration to know how it’s declared. But it’s not the only way to produce this error.

Comment: Thanks for your post, rob. I hope Don Abril was able to fix his error.

Comment: Hello all! I was able to solve the problem using @Paulw11 's comment. Simply removing the return statement had my app running like a well-oiled machine. I really appreciate you guys taking the time to help another out. And thanks, Mr. Roué, for GRDB.

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case when you have a problem with a generic type in Swift, the error message is not helpful.

Here’s the real problem:

1. `DB.write` is generic in its argument and return type. It has a type parameter `T`. The closure argument’s return type is `T`, and the `write` method itself returns `T`.
2. The closure you’re passing is more than a single expression. It is a multi-statement closure. Swift does not deduce the type of a multi-statement closure from the statements in the closure. This is just a limitation of the compiler, for practical reasons.
3. Your program doesn’t specify the type `T` explicitly or otherwise provide constraints that would let Swift deduce the concrete type.

These characteristics of your program mean Swift doesn’t know concrete type to use for `T`. So the compiler’s type checker/deducer fails. You would expect to get an error message about this problem.  (Possibly an inscrutable message, but presumably at least relevant).

But that’s not what you get, because you declared `DB` as `DatabaseQueue!`.

Since `DB` is an implicitly-unwrapped optional, the type checker handles it specially by (as you might guess) automatically unwrapping it **if** doing so makes the statement type-check when the statement would otherwise **not** type-check. In all other ways, the type of `DB` is just plain `DatabaseQueue?`, a regular `Optional`.

In this case, the statement won’t type-check even with automatic unwrapping, because of the error I described above: Swift can’t deduce the concrete type to substitute for `T`. Since the statement doesn’t type-check either way, Swift doesn’t insert the unwrapping for you. Then it carries on as if `DB` were declared `DatabaseQueue?`.

Since `DatabaseQueue?` doesn’t have a `write` method (because `Optional` doesn’t have a `write` method), the call `DB.write` is erroneous. So Swift wants to print an error message. But it “helpfully” sees that the wrapped type, `DatabaseQueue`, **does** have a `write` method. And by this point it has completely forgotten that `DB` was declared implicitly-unwrapped.  So it tells you to unwrap `DB` to get to the `write` method, **even though** it would have done that automatically if it hadn’t encountered another error in this statement.

So anyway, you need to tell Swift what type to use for `T`. I suspect you meant to say this:

```
var locsCountInFloor: Int
do {
    locsCountInFloor = try DB.write { db in
        ...
```

Assigning the result of the `DB.write` call to the outer `locsCountInFloor` is sufficient to fix the error, because you already explicitly defined the type of `locsCountInFloor`. From that, Swift can deduce the return type of this call to `DB.write`, and from that the type of the closure.

Comment: Hello, rob. I find out that it was the return statement inside the try block that was causing my problem. I appreciate you taking the time to help me with my problem, and I apologize for any inconvenience writing your answer may have caused you.